# Reset Knockout observable variables to its start value

Tags: knockout.js, observable, reset

I'm curious to know if Knockout implement a method to reset a observable variable to its start value. For example:

```
var test = ko.observable("test");

test("ciao");
test.reset();
```

value come back to "test". Exist something like this or a field that save the start value?

Comment: Include it in a viewmodel and just create a new instance persay to initialize the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if adding functions to an observable via an [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) is good practice, but you could add this functionality like so:

```js
ko.extenders.canReset = function(target, enabled) {
  // If enabled, we assign a reset method bound to target's current value:
  return enabled
    ? Object.assign(target, { reset: target.bind(null, target()) })
    : target;
};

var myObs = ko.observable(10).extend({ canReset: true });
myObs.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, "new value:"));

myObs(20);
myObs(30);

// Reset
myObs.reset();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

If it feels wrong to "randomly" add a method to the observable, you could also look in to the [`fn`-way of adding functionality](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html).

Comment: thanks I've always been using this.myvalue = ko.observable(myvalue) this.OriginalmyValue = ko.observable(myvalue) I like what you have done much better.

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you for the share!